# Async callback from class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am writing a class in JavaScript that would send an HTTP request for a specified URL and then would return the body of the response. I am new to Node.js and JavaScript, therefore, I am having a really hard time understanding the callbacks and async nature of Nodejs.

I wrote the actual method that fetches the URL, and it works fine. The result is available passed to the Mocha test.

```
class HttpObject {
  constructor () {
    this.url = null
    this.userAgent = null
    this.body = null
  }

  fetchUrl (url, userAgent, callback) {
    this.url = url
    this.userAgent = userAgent

    const request = require('request')
    request(this.url, { timeout: 10000 }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        //the next line doesn't work, the 'body' field in Mocha test is null
        this.body = response.body
        return callback(response, false)
      } else {
        return callback(null, error)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But when I test the body field of the HttpObject, it's still assigned `null`. Though, it should have been assigned the body of the result.

```
it('should send and http request to https://www.google.com', function (done) {
  httpObj.fetchUrl('https://www.google.com', 'Mozilla/5.0', (res, err) => {
    assert.strictEqual(httpObj.getUrl(), 'https://www.google.com')
    assert.strictEqual(httpObj.getPort(), 80)
    assert.strictEqual(httpObj.getUserAgent(), 'Mozilla/5.0')

    // previous tests pass, but the following doesn't
    assert.notStrictEqual(httpObj.getBody(), null)

    done()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the context `this` is lost when a function is called from outside the class that created that function. ( mostly a callback )

In your case, because `function (error, response, body)` is being called from somewhere else, it doesn't know the value of `this`.

To solve this, either you can use `fat arrow` functions like this:

```
request(this.url, { timeout: 10000 }, (error, response, body) => {
    // you can now set this.body here safely
})
```

or you can use `.bind(this)` on the callback

```
request(this.url, { timeout: 10000 }, function (error, response, body) {
    // you can now set this.body here safely
}.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.body` statement in the your HttpObject is in a different scope then the rest of your `this` values because its a callback of `request`. Try adding a `var that = this` above the callback from your request.

```js
class HttpObject {
  constructor () {
    this.url = null
    this.userAgent = null
    this.body = null
  }

  fetchUrl (url, userAgent, callback) {
    // add var that
    var that = this;
    this.url = url
    this.userAgent = userAgent

    const request = require('request')
    request(this.url, { timeout: 10000 }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        // Change the value to that.
        that.body = response.body

        return callback(response, false)
      } else {
        return callback(null, error)
      }
    })
  }
}
```